# Call Javascript function from dynamically loaded inner function

Tags: javascript, function

My main application loads javascript files based on the 'page' visited:

```
var AdminConsole = (function() {
    function openPage(folder, template) {
        $.getScript('viewmodels/' + template + '.js')
            .done(function() {
                console.log(template + " script loaded.");
            });
    }
    function test() {
        // do something ...
    }
})();
```

The javascript being loaded in `$.getScript()` looks like this:

```
var UserPermissions = (function() {
    // try to call test()
})();
```

My question is, how do I call `AdminConsole.test()` from within `UserPermissions()`?

When I try `AdminConsole.test()` it says AdminConsole is undefined. And when I try just `test()`, test is undefined.

Comment: Define AdminConsole gloablly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value assigned to `AdminConsole` is the value returned by that anonymous function. Since you don't return anything, it's `undefined`.

Instead, you should export the public methods/properties:

```js
var AdminConsole = (function() {
    // ... (private data)
    return { // Export public data to the outside
        test: test,
        openPage: openPage
    };
})();
```

If you don't need private data, you can also consider the simpler

```js
var AdminConsole = {
    test: function(){ /*...*/ },
    openPage: function(){ /*...*/ }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

AdminConsole appears to be the result of calling a function. If that function does not have a `return`, then AdminConsole will be undefined.
Perhaps you want this:

```
AdminConsole = {
    openPage: ...
    test: ...
}
```

But what you probably want is to use modules, as provided by [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, `AdminConsole` is a self-executing, anonymous function. In other words, it is equal to whatever `(function () {/* your code*/})()` returns. In your case above, you don't return anything (you just have functions inside of the anonymous function), so `AdminConsole == undefined`. Those functions are private. For example,

```
function myPrivateData () {
    this.data = "public";
    var nobodyCanSee = "private";
}
var test = new myPrivateData();
// test.data => "public"
// test.nobodyCanSee => undefined
```

This is the same as your situation. None of your inner functions are attached to the anonymous function, so they're invisible outside of that function's scope.

If you want to access the functions within `AdminConsole`, you can make it an object:

```
var adminConsole = {
    openPage: function () {
        // etc
    },
    test: function () {
        // etc
    }
}
```

With this structure, you can call `test` with `adminConsole.test()`.

Comment: I don't see what closures have to do with this. It looks like things are just not being defined as the OP expected.

Comment: There is "a" closure involved here, but it isn't the focus of the question or the problem in the question.

Comment: @JonSurrell I mean, it has to do with scope, but I can probably remove that first sentence.